# Cannot login to Google Cloud Virtual Machine with IAM and two factor through SSH

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-iam

After I have created a Virtual Machine that runs latest Ubuntu LTS I want to connect to it using SSH.

When I login to it I get this screen:

[image]

I get a new code from g.co/sc

[image]

When I enter that code into the SSH-in-browser the same screen appears again.

What am I doing wrong?

**1) Setup of Virtual Machine**

*Machine Configuration*

- Type: E2 Standard 4 (4 vCPU, 16 GB RAM)
- Display Device: Enable

*Boot disk*

- OS: Ubuntu LTS x86/64

*Identity and API access*

- Firewall: Allow HTTPS traffic

*Security*

- Shielded VM: Turn on Secure Boot

*VM Access*

- Control VM access through IAM permissions
- Require 2-Step Verification

*Custom metadata*

- enable-oslogin: true
- enable-oslogin-2fa: true

**2) Permissions for vm**

*I have added myself to the following permissions:*

- Compute Admin
- Compute Instance Admin
- Compute OS Admin Login
- Compute OS Login
- Compute Viewer
- Owner

Comment: Suggest to disable the **IP check**. Under the security codes section, there is a check box **"Allow security codes with remote access"**, by following the below steps in the Admin console:

**In the Admin console, go to Menu and then [Security] then [Authentication and then2-step verification]**, Under the security codes section, there is a check box **Allow security codes with remote access**.

Comment: Have you tried the above comment and it helped you to resolve your  issue?

Comment: This worked. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to hear that. The same provided as an answer. Feel free to Accept and upvote the answer for better community visibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To resolve your issue, **disable the IP check**. Under the security codes section, there is a check box `Allow security codes with remote access`, you can do by following the below steps in the Admin console: **In the Admin console, go to Menu and then [Security] then [Authentication and then2-step verification]**, Under the security codes section, there is a check box **Allow security codes with remote access**.